# add elements to regex in routes based on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following setup in my routes.rb file:

`scope '(:institution)', institution: /acme/ do`

however I would like to add more institutions to limit based on the names in my institution column of the db. How do I go about cleanly adding it to the regex as a function instead of just doing `/acme|acme1|acme2/` etc

EDIT: I followed Cary Swoveland's comment and did this:

`scope '(:institution)', institution: Regexp.union(Institution.pluck(:custom_sign_up_name).compact) do`

It works when my database is already created, however if I try to run:

`rake db:drop db:setup` it tells me that the table doesn't exist in the DB:

`` ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'ejbdev.institutions' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `institutions` ``

How do I get around this? I need to be able to drop and recreate the DB for CI to pass

Comment: Perhaps [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union) would be of use. It will also do any necessary escaping of characters that have significant in regex expression (such as `"+"` or `"*"`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks! reading that helped me out.. but I have problems creating the DB now. When the DB is already there its fine, but If I have to call rake to setup the DB I get an error. Updated my question above

Comment: snowflakekiller, sorry, I don't know Rails.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  no worries, you got me in the right direction. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by handling the exception:

```
class DynamicRouter
  def self.load
    institutions = retrieve_institutions_with_custom_sign_up_names
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      scope '(:institution)', institution: institutions do
        devise_scope :user do
          get ':institution' => 'devise/sessions#new'
        end
        get 'omniauth/:provider' => 'omniauth#institution', as: :institution_omniauth
        devise_for :users, skip: [:invitation, :omniauth_callbacks], controllers: { sessions: 'devise/sessions', registrations: 'devise/registrations' }
      end
    end
  end

  def self.reload
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end

  private

  def self.retrieve_institutions_with_custom_sign_up_names
    Regexp.union(Institution.pluck(:custom_sign_up_name).compact)
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
      return ''
  end
```